# How to track User Conversion Rate by iTunes Affiliate Link within an iOS App

Tags: ios, app-store, affiliate

Given the following scenario:

- An affiliate link is clicked to route the user to the iTunes App Store

  - Shouldn't matter if the link is clicked on the device itself or on a Mac/PC.
  - (Whereas the links are those links from LinkShare for instance)
- The app is then being installed on an iOS device.
- As soon as the user starts a certain action (for example buying in-app-purchases), this action will be logged together with the original Id of the affiliate ID, which made the user install the app.

The goal is to be able to track "converting users" (aka conversion rates) in dependance of the affiliate. Example: "60% of the users brought by Affiliate XY converted from non-paying to paying users".

What would be the best practice to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much every campaign analytic service should allow you to set this up just fine. One I know for sure does as I set it up last week for a project is

[AppsFlyer: Mobile Apps Installation & Conversion Tracking](http://www.appsflyer.com)

In issue 101 of iosdevweekly there was a Tapstream promotion so I took a look at that and they look like they'd do the job fine as well:

[Tapstream: App Marketing, Unified.](https://tapstream.com)

If neither of those look perfect, [here's a bunch of other competitors](http://build.developereconomics.com/sector/app-promotion-campaign-analytics/) you can check out too.